# What's the best way to replay keystrokes on to my terminal?

Tags: terminal, expect

I find myself having to do a series of `ssh` in order to get to a particular host. What I currently do is to copy and paste the commands into the terminal, one after the another, like a machine. I'm wondering if there's a way replay these fixed commands into my terminal.

I do use `tmux`, and I'm aware of `tmux send`; but I'd want to be doing this "intelligently", in that I want to wait for the prompt before I send the next ssh command. I'm also aware of `expect`, but the usages I've seen are where the terminal is `spawn`ed from within the script and interacted from within—and the spawned terminal dies with the expect script.

What would be ideal is if I can get `expect` to do its thing on the very terminal that I've open. Is there a way to do that, or are there alternatives?

Comment: With expect, you can spawn a _shell_ (that lives inside the terminal window), and the spawned shell can remain open if you choose to `interact` with the shell at the end of the expect script.

Comment: One cool tmux feature is that you can split the window into subpanes. Each subpane can ssh to a different host. Then the panes can be synchronized so that typing (or pasting) into one pane is mirrored in all the other panes simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `expect`'s `interact` command, as one of the comments above mention. The general template is like this:

```
spawn ssh ...
send "some keys"
expect {
  ...
}
interact
```